# In HTML, role ="menu" is not recognized and its showing error

Tags: html, html-lists

As new to the software field and am on learning all those stuffs. While trying to workout with the bootstrap, I encounter this sort of error.

[While typing role=menu its showing red underline for ul and yellow underline in li](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnFeE.png)

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting images of code or error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.